# How to set pop up width width maximum using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open a popup window using javascript method:

```
window.resizeTo(1300,500);
```

But this is not working. The browser that it is supposed to work in is IE.
So I want to know if there is a way I can set width to full width of screen, irrespective of pixel size, like when we use "100%" width in css it cover the whole width. Something like that.

Comment: `The browser that it is supposed to work in is IE` IE has (too) many different versions of the same thing, down to which version do you need to support? Which version are you testing on?

Comment: `<a href="newWindowPath" _target="_blank">Text</a>` or `window.open("url")`

Comment: I am using IE 11. But other that IE 11 let me know if there is something for IE 10 too.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the popup opens after a form submission. So when the popup page opens, I use js with onload method to resize it.

Comment: Are you including the 'resizable' attribute in the window.open() call? Else resizeTo() won't work. Or is it the form submission that loads the popup?  I usually just write a real HTML file for an external popup, including a CSS stylesheet.

Comment: So what's wrong with `window.open("someURL",,"width=" + screen.width)`?

Comment: @Shilly yes I'm already using resizable. Like I said, it is working on my system but not after deployment on server.

Comment: @Scott will try screen.width with resizeTo tomorrow

Comment: @ScottMarcus screen.width did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I tried width = screen.width in js. See comments to question for more details. Credit to [Scott Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695364/scott-marcus)